# Return rows that match all the boolean values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
    ID  |  Boolean 
    ================
    1   | TRUE     
    1   | FALSE  
    1   | TRUE
    2   | TRUE 
    2   | TRUE
    2   | FALSE
    3   | FALSE
    3   | FALSE
    3   | FALSE
```

What I am trying to get is the ID that only comes up as 'false' in the Boolean column, so my result should look like

```
    3
```

My rough SQL is as follows:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Boolean
    FROM FakeTable
    WHERE Boolean = 'False'
```

About as basic as you can get. However, of course when I do this, I get the following result:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

Obviously because each of the ID's have at least one 'False' in the boolean column. How might I narrow this down?

Comment: You can use `not exists`. (Or google, this question has been asked many, many times before)

Answer (score 3):

One quick option

Assuming `Boolean` is a `BIT`, we can use the implicit conversion, hence the `0+Boolean`

```
Select ID 
 from YourTable
 Group By ID
 Having max(0+Boolean)=0
```

Comment: You know what happens when you assume... :-)

Comment: @Tanner All too well  :)

Comment: why `0 + Boolean` and not just `Boolean`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza another way to deal with that would be to convert boolean to a tinyint. Here he is just using implicit conversion to int. :)

Answer (score 1):

This gives only the ones that have false and not a true component.

I changed from a nested query to a JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.Boolean
    FROM FakeTable A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FakeTable B on A.ID=B.ID AND B.Boolean='True'
    WHERE A.Boolean = 'False' AND B.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT DISCTINCT ID
FROM FakeTable ft1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ID
    FROM FakeTable ft2
    WHERE ft2.ID = ft1.ID
    AND ft2.Boolean = 'True'
)
```

This I haven't tested, but should also work:

```
SELECT ID
FROM FakeTable
GROUP By ID
HAVING MAX(CASE Boolean WHEN 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregate Function `SUM`

> You need to Convert BIT to INT because BIT is invalid for SUM Operator

```
SELECT ID
FROM FakeTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CAST(Boolean AS INT)) = 0
```